# How to merge three dataframes to avoid NA values (R)?

Tags: r

I have a long dataset with responses at time 1 and time 2.

I am trying to join two other dataframes (df1 and df2) to my primary dataframe (df) to create `df_join`. I've tried the following code, but it results in four separate columns: `var1.x`, `var2.x`, `var1.y`, `var2.y` where I would like just `var1` and `var2`

What is the best approach here?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002), time = c(1, 2, 1, 2), var3 = c("324908", "1231", "23532", "09094")
df1 <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1002), time = c(1, 1), var1 = c(300, 400), var2 = c(300, 400))
df2 <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1002), time = c(2, 2), var1 = c(310, 410), var2 = c(320, 420))

df_join <- df %>% 
  left_join(select(df1, ID, var1, var2), by = c("ID")) %>% 
  left_join(select(df2, ID, var1, var2), by = c("ID"))
```

My desired output would be:

```
df_join_desire <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002), time = c(1, 2, 1, 2), var1 = c(300, 310, 400, 410), var2 = c(300, 320, 400, 420), var3 = c(324908, 1231, 23532, 09094))
```

Comment: looks like you should `bind_rows(df1, df2)` first and then `join()`

Comment: @akrun Updated post to include desired output.

Comment: also the information in `df` is redundant with what you have in the other two so it is not needed in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering this error because `df1` and `df2` have the same column names, so you don't need to `left_join` them together, you can simply bind them (i.e., putting the new rows of `df2` at the bottom of `df1`).

```
df_join <- left_join(df, bind_rows(df1, df2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find append `df1` and `df2` to each other.

```
df_join <- df |> left_join(bind_rows(df1, df2), by = c("ID", "time"))
```